# CSS , wordwrapping pre tag in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

Need best practice for styling `<pre>` tag in Safari

Here's my code in Chrome :

[image: Chrome render]

Meanwhile here's what it looks like in Safari :

[image: Safari Render]

any idea guys?

```
pre{
    border:0;
    border-radius:0;
    border-top:$orange 2px solid;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-wrap:normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to look in the Developer Tools in Chrome to find out which properties are set and how by the browser by default.

Then you'll find out that you additionally need to define **`white-space: normal;`** (or similar, like you want it to behave).

The same thing you should do on other browsers like Safari or Firefox to *"normalize"* the appearance.

Comment: got it, the proper css to define is `word-wrap:normal;`

Comment: Oh. I thought you wanted the result in Chrome to look like in Safari. But I'm glad I could help anyway.  :)

Comment: ahaha its other way around, it's pretty hard to normalise Safari, did you guys guideline or checklist to follow?

Comment: There are normalize/reset css-files out there, which do pretty most of that. Just inform yourself which betters suits your needs.

Comment: well I'm creating this in top of bootstrap, pretty sure that have normalize.css. And no that is just the piece of css that responsible.

Answer (score 2):

You can get this to work by embedding <code> within a <pre> and using a webkit-specific property so the <code> block extends past the edge of the <pre> tag contents:

```html
<pre>
    <code class="language-css">
       ..your code
    </code>
</pre>

<style type="text/css">

    pre {
        overflow-x: scroll;
    }

    pre > code {
        width: -webkit-max-content;
    }

</style>
```

I use this with prism.js and it works well, even on iOS.